# Jquery Countdown Plugin Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, countdown

I am using JQuery's countdown plugin in my Django application. I set up the countdown init script in a JQuery document.ready callback function, and I can see the javascript load when I check the network tab in Chrome's web inspector, but the plugin doesn't show up. I logged the element to the web console to make sure that it existed when I tried to call JQuery.countdown's .countDown method that kickstarts the plugin. It does in fact exist, but there is just empty space in between the tags. There are also no errors in the console.

Scripts "both JQuery and JQuery countdown being loaded"

```
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/js/menu.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/js/user_actions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.countdown/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

    <!-- JQUERY Countdown -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var clock = $("#countdown");
            console.log(clock);

            $("#countdown").countDown("2017/12/01", function (event) {
                console.log("CLOCK WORKS");
                $(this).text(
                        event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
{% block content %}

    <div id='billboard' class='flexslider billboards'>

        <ul class='slides'>

            {% for billboard in billboards %}
                <li class='slide' style="background-image: url('{{ billboard.image }}');">

                    <div class='transparent-overlay'></div>

                    <div class='container'>

                        <div class='slide-content'>

                            <h1>{% inplace_edit "billboard.header" %}</h1>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </li>
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="home-sub-container">
        <div class="col-xs-8" style="border: 1px solid lime;">
            <div id="daily-sales-tracker" style="height: 500px; background-color: lightgray; margin-bottom: 30px;"></div>

            <div id="additional-plugins" style="height: 500px; background-color: lightgray;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 red-alerts">
            <p>RED ALERTS</p>
            <div class="styled-divider">
                <div class="color"></div>
                <div class="no-color"></div>
            </div>
            {% for alert in red_alerts %}
                <div class="red-alert">
                    <div class="fa-container">
                        {% if alert.font_awesome_one %}
                            <i class="fa {{ alert.font_awesome_one }}"></i>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if alert.font_awesome_two %}
                            <i class="fa {{ alert.font_awesome_two }}"></i>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if alert.font_awesome_three %}
                            <i class="fa {{ alert.font_awesome_three }}"></i>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <p class="alert-title">
                        {{ alert.title }}
                    </p>
                    <a href="{{ alert.link }}" class="alert-links">
                        DOWNLOAD
                    </a>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <div id="countdown">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id='sections' class='home-sections'>

        {% for section in sections %}
            <div class='section-wrapper {% cycle "white" "dark" %}'>

                <div class='container'>

                    <div class='row'>

                        {% inplace_edit 'section.content|safe' adaptor='tiny' %}
                        <div class='clear-both'></div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class='clear-both'></div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You are loading the jquery.countdown.js twice.  Can you try removing one of the references?

Comment: Ah sorry, I commented it out cause I tried two different versions, but I forgot to not include it in the question. It has been removed.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with this issue?

Comment: One sec, let me try and create one.

Comment: I did a Codepen instead https://codepen.io/timbaney1989/pen/LjeGEx, hope that works.

Comment: check if this helps - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzJGMR

Comment: Thanks Madhan, that did the trick. I wasn't aware I had to include the time tag inside the target element. Now the tricky part, reversing the clock so it goes up instead of down hah.